# Toyota aygo damage repair

Tags: toyota, tires, repair, damage

I damaged my Toyota Aygo Spice Edition, on the left rocker panel because I had a flat tire.

Also the 14" alloy wheels (6-spoke) is damaged and needs to be replaced with a new one.

Would it be viable to replace these? Any suggestions acceptable!

Sorry for my English (from Cyprus).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pricing questions are off topic for the site, unfortunately. They tend to become obsolete rather quickly.

Comment: If it's a plastic rocker you can try heating it and pulling the dent out.

Comment: How did you damage the wheel?

Comment: I replaced an aluminum wheel on a Nissan Murano. The dealer price was outrageous. I got one from the internet for 85 % less .  Of course , I have no idea what the internet in Cyprus is like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you can get the rocker panel fixed, if you really worry about the looks of the car, the dent I see is not gonna hurt the performance though, so it is up to you.

If I am in your shoes, I would not even worry about it, cause the pinch weld looks great so you can jack the car up without a problem.

Comment: I depends on the material of the rocker panel, if it is plastic you can remove it from the car, heat the area by pushing on the inside you can pop it to the original shape and you don't need to paint it. If it is metal then it purely depends on the procedure followed there are paint less dent removal techniques and with some other procedures you might have to get it painted.
From the pictures it looks like it is metal, so at this point your chances are leaning towards getting it painted after the dent is fixed.